# Auto cast void pointer to pointer to double in function call

Tags: c, function, pointers, casting, void-pointers

I have a question, and it might already be answered somewhere else, and I could not find it, so I apologize if it already exists.

I have the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(double *number) {
    printf("%f\n", *number);
}

void bar(void *number) {
    double *new_number = (double *)number;
    printf("%f\n", *new_number);
}

int main()
{
    double test_number = 3.0;
    double *test_double_pointer = &test_number;
    void *test_void_pointer = (void *)test_double_pointer;
    
    foo(test_double_pointer);
    foo(test_void_pointer);
    bar(test_double_pointer);
    bar(test_void_pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

the result is

```
3.000000
3.000000
3.000000
3.000000
```

I don't understand what is happening under the hood. How does the C compiler handle these function calls?

Comment: In most architectures, all pointers are the same, so it doesn't need to do anything under the hood.

Comment: Aside: you don't need to cast assignments to or from `void*` pointers.

Comment: @WeatherVane They partially understand that, since there are no casts in the function calls.

Comment: `void*` can automatically cast to anything. (Only in C, not in C++)

Comment: But let's say, I have something more complicated (a struct, for example). At least the compiler needs to know, how the memory is structured, the pointer is pointing to?

Comment: Yes, that's why you can't do anything with a `void*` type except pass it around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a good example of how to use `void` pointers to pass data of any type between functions.

#### §6.3.2.3 Pointers (C11 N1570)

> 1. *A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.*

Not much happening under the hood, compilers must assure the above rule is respected. An easy way is to do this is to have all pointer types be the same size.

Importantly, the compiler also needs to know the pointer type in order to perform the usual pointer arithmetic and operations.

Answer (score 2):

> How does the C compiler handle these function calls?

Your compilers knows how to convert the pointers. Specifically,

- Your C compiler knows how to convert from a `double *` to a `void *`.
- Your C compiler knows how to convert from a `double *` that's been converted to `void *` back to a `double *`.

(On the machines you're likely to use, no actual conversion is needed.)

And it knows when to do it. Specifically,

- When you cast to `void *`, it knows it needs a `void *`.
- When you cast to `double *`, it knows it needs a `double *`.
- When you assign to a `void *`, it knows it needs a `void *`.
- When you assign to a `double *`, it knows it needs a `double *`.
- When the parameter has type `void *`, it knows it needs a `void *` argument.
- When the parameter has type `double *`, it knows it needs a `double *` argument.

(You don't do all of these, but I wanted to include some common cases.)

Comment: When a parameter has type `void *` you can typically pass any type of pointer, eg `memset()` and `free()`.

Comment: Yes, but it can only be converted to a `double *` if it was originally a `double *`.

Comment: I am trying to say that "When the parameter has type `void *`, it knows it needs a `void *` argument" is incorrect. You can pass any type of pointer to a `void*` parameter.

Comment: @ikegami Not universally.  The conversion is allowed if properly aligned for the target type.

Comment: @dbush, No, it's far more limited than that. For example, even if a `char *` and a `double *` have the same alignment restrictions (like on an x86 and x86-64), `char c = '!'; double *p = (void *)&c;` will give you junk. Accessing `*p` is UB. Even if they have the same size (like `long *` and `double *` might), you again get junk even if not UB. You could cast the `const` away, but that's far outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: @Weather Vane, It's not incorrect. You seem to think I said you need to use an expression that results in a `void *`. But I said nothing of the sort. I said the compiler knows that it has to convert it to a `void *`. The answer says the opposite of what you think it says.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the variable names are a bit confusing (and the title before edit too). Usually, double pointer is understood as a pointer to a pointer, not the pointer to `double`.

Someone probably was using C++ compiler to compile the C code. C++ and C are different languages having their own rules.

In C language you do not need to cast from or to `void *`. In C++ it requires an explicit cast and this code without the casts will not compile https://godbolt.org/z/78KbW4Wdz

Under the hood, the compiler simply needs to know what data type the pointer is referencing.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you nay change the function bar the following way

```
void bar(void *number) {
    double *new_number = number;
    printf("%f\n", *new_number);
}
```

removing explicit casting.

In C a pointer of the type void * can be assigned to a pointer to object of any other type.

So in this calls

```
foo(test_void_pointer);
bar(test_double_pointer);
```

the pointers of the type void * may be assigned to parameters of the type double * and vice versa pointers of the type double * can be assigned to parameters of the type void *.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
> object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
> pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the
> original pointer.